# Node.js/Mongodb/GridFS resize images on upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, mongodb, gridfs-stream

I am saving uploaded images in Mongodb GridFS with Node.js/Express/gridfs-stream/multyparty using streams.
Works fine.

Now I would like to "normalize" (resize) images to some standard format before storing to database.

- I could use **gm** https://github.com/aheckmann/gm and have streaming but I would have to install native ImageMagic (not an option) or
- Use something like **lwip** https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip and have a "pure Node" setup, but then I cannot have streaming

So is there a solution to have a streaming solution to request -> resize -> store to GridFS without installing external libraries?

Current solution (missing the resize step):

```
function storeImage(req, err, succ){
  var conn = mongoose.connection;
  var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
  var context = {};

  var form = new multiparty.Form();

  form.on('field', function(name, value){
    context[name] = value;
    console.log(context);
  });

  form.on('part', function(part){
    // handle events only if file part
    if (!part.filename) { return; }

    var options =
    {
      filename: part.filename,
      metadata: context,
      mode: 'w',
      root: 'images'
    };
    var ws = gfs.createWriteStream(options);

    // success GridFS
    ws.on('close', function (file) {
      console.log(file.filename + file._id);
      succ(file._id);
    });

    // error GridFS
    ws.on('error', function (errMsg) {
      console.log('An error occurred!', errMsg);
      err(errMsg);
    });

    part.pipe(ws);
  });

  // Close emitted after form parsed
  form.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Upload completed!');
  });

  form.parse(req);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity

1) Initially I used lwip while I was storing images locally. When people started uploading bigger images (which was added as requirement) lwip started exploding my instance on Heroku and I switched to

2) gm over ImageMagick running on AWS Lambda that has ImageMagick preconfigured in the default instance. Images now stored on S3 and distributed via CloudFront.